# Uploading file in mapped drive using asp.net

Tags: .net, iis

I have two servers. Application server and File server. I need to upload files directly to File server.so far what i have done is, when i upload i received "**unknown user name and bad password error**" .so i created an user name and password in file server like in the Application server (IUSR_ account. exact like in the application server). 
Now i receive "**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path \xxx\xx... is denied**".Then i granted the network service user as full permission in File server shared folder. still i get the UnauthorizedAccessException. And one more, the application pool is running under the identity of network user. Help needed.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Probably becuase the Network service user is running under the server workgroup. Set up a user on the mapped drive server and on the IIS server with the same name and password on both

Comment: that is what i did it in both servers. After that only i got UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: Then why is the app pool running as network user and not the other one?

Comment: I changed to the user what i run under IUSR account. But the site went down.then i reverted back. Its production site...

Comment: You will have to run the app service as a custom user as the network service account does not have equal passwords on both servers and thus will not be authenticated. Don't change this password

Answer (score 1):

Are the machines part of the same domain? In that case you give the *machine* account (called machinename$) of the app server access to the file server. Then you run the app server app pool under the "network service" account. You also have to access the file server with a complete unc path (`\\server\share\directory`) as mapped drives are tied to a specific user.

If you're not in a domain environment you need to add code so that the app server logs on to the file server when attaching the network share. Having the same username/password pair on both the client and server is something that works magically when logging on interactively, but for services that is not an option.

Comment: Our servers is not in domain. its workgroup.I have clearly mentioned the UNC Path (\\192.168.10.20\Transcode_Central\EV_Process\) Also i created an same username and password in file server as like in application server. Which is in the iis IUSR_MAchinename account

Comment: Given full permission on shared folder to network service,asp.net,iusr account that is newly created.